# Cognates or coincidences?

Tags: etymology

Recently, I read an **[article](http://idibon.com/toxicity-in-reddit-communities-a-journey-to-the-darkest-depths-of-the-interwebs/)** about so-called toxic behavior on reddit, posted on a website named "idibon". I thought idi- was a reference to idiotic, e.g. the **[website Wikipediocracy](http://wikipediocracy.com/press-release/)**, which is presumably a variant on idiocracy, or idiotic governance. However, I found that "idibon" is actually a text analysis company. The **[idi- in Idibon refers to language](https://twitter.com/idibon/status/591655072049704960)**, e.g. "idiom" or "idiomatic".

This is my question: Is there any etymological relationship between any of these three, idi- prefixed words,

- idiotic
- idiomatic
- idiopathic

and if so, what is it? Are they cognates? Is the resemblance coincidental?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idio– prefix means, indeed, self.

Idiot

- Ancient Greece was a deeply political society, one in which every citizen was expected to vote and engage in the political process. Exceptions were granted only for persons who were mentally incapable. These people were allowed to be, more or less, citizens only of their self (idios). That's how they have become known as 'idiots'.
- By reverse, a citizen who by choice, rather occupied themselves with their own business and not that of the polis were seen as not much better than those who did so not by choice but owing to their intellectual deficiencies. This is presumably where the negative connotation of the term largely comes from.
- An alternative explanation is that ίδιωτής meant something both literally and contextually akin to our term 'private (soldier)' - a soldier who is low-ranking and usually conscripted (used by [Polybius](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/citequery3.pl?dbname=GreekFeb2011&query=Polyb.%201.69.9&getid=1) in this way) and lacking skill..

Idiopathic

An idiopathic condition is one where the disease process (-pathy) is almost occurring 'by itself' (idio-), rather than by a known secondary cause. Again, there is this element of self-enclosedness and self-reflexivity.

Idiomatic

An ἰδίωμα was something that was so characteristic - we might even say *idiosyncratic*! - that it was peculiar to the self. It was a turn of phrase of an individual (again, this self-reflexivity aspect of idio-) that became used by others.

Comment: Is *rather t* a typo?

Comment: No - it's a sentence I for some reason didn't finish. I apologise. I will amend now.

Answer (score 1):

They are cognates only in that they share the prefix idio- which is from the Greek **idios** meaning private or personal (another word to list among these is *id*.)

An *idiot* listens only to himself. Originally this meant not a moron, just one who was oblivious to common conventions.

An *idiom* is a way of saying something that originated with one person saying it, then it caught on and became an accepted part of the language. It became *idiomatic*.

An *idiopathic* condition is a malady that does not match any known diseases; thus, it seems to be unique to one person.

No mystery here, just simple roots-and-prefixes.

But be careful not to lump these with **ideo-**  prefixed words , such as *ideology*.  this prefix means "idea".

List:  https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_prefixed_with_ideo-